# Help with DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Im new to webforms.

Right now I have a DetailsView of a single client... what I want is that before the view is displayed, if the client doesnt have an email defined, redirect to a different page.. how can I get the data from the objectdatasource and redirect??

help please.

Here's my ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="GetDataByCodigo" 
        TypeName="PanamaBanks.DataSetTableAdapters.ClientesTableAdapter">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Codigo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CodigoBanco" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Nombre" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Apellido" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Negocio" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Telefono" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="0" FormField="codigo" Name="Codigo" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check emails value while DetailsView is being binded to data by attaching DataBound event like this: in aspx page

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="detailsView" 
            ondatabound="detailsView_DataBound"></asp:DetailsView>
```

and in code behind

protected void detailsView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView view = (DetailsView)sender;

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)view.DataItem;
if (drv != null)
{
    if (Convert.IsDBNull(drv["Email"]))
        //redirect - email column has null value
        Redirect();

    if (drv["Email"].ToString().Trim() == string.Empty)
        //redirect - email column is empty 
        Redirect();
}
```

}

Comment: This looks close to what I need but I still dont get how to the the value of the email column from just that.... please help

Comment: if you paste here your objectdatasource code then I may help u in finding email column

Comment: After trying that Im getting Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'. Maybe I should point out Im using .net 2.0

Comment: i see, then just cast it to DataRowView instead of DataTable just like i did in edited code above. Hope this will work now.

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your codebehind. Check for a null value in the email field, and redirect if found. Something like this (C#):

```
if(client.email==""){
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ReDirect("differentPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Im not using Linq to SQL... the Details.aspx has a DetailsView Control which is mapped to a ObjectDataSource of a clients table on my database.. I dont think I can just do "client.email"

Comment: Use the OnSelected Event. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389571/can-you-get-a-datatable-from-an-objectdatasource